# How to run a function on click event? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried many ways and now I am desperate. I can't get my code to work. I need to run one function with 3 different arguments on three different button cicks.

One HTML file:

```
<div class="counter">
 <div id="clockdiv">
     <h1><span class="minutes timeText"></span></h1>
     <h1><span class="seconds timeText"></span></h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Other html file:

```
<div class="main">
   <a href="session.html" id="5min"><div class="button-part-30">
       <button class="button button-calm">5min</button>
       </div></a>
    <a href="session.html"><div class="button-part-30">
        <button id="10min"  class="button button-calm">10min</button>
        </div></a>
     <a href="session.html"><div class="button-part-30">
       <button id="20min"  class="button button-calm">20min</button>
         </div></a>
</div>
```

jQuery and JS:

```
function startCounter(x){
var t = x * 60000 + 1001;

function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  for (t; t = t - 1000; t >= 1000){

  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
};
};

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
function updateClock(){
  var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
  if(t.total <= 1){
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  };
};

updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}


initializeClock('clockdiv', t);
};
```

When I run `startSession(20)` or some other number then all seems to work.
But I need to run this function by clicking on those buttons that are located in other html file. Also counter starts on completely different html file. I am very low beginner level. Thanks!

Comment: HTML element `id`s should begin with a letter, not a number.

Comment: i guess that is one of the stupidest mistakes i've made. Thanks for reply!